# call a function, pointed by a function pointer member in a structure array

Tags: c, arrays, structure, function-pointers

I would like to call a function, pointed by a function pointer member in a structure array.

In run time, I want to order different functions to the function pointers.

Somehow, the functions are not invoked. Can You explain me, why?

**My code is:**

```
typedef struct 
{
    char c; // several simple type variables...
    int(*eventhandler)(int param);  // function pointer member (maybe, it would do with double indirection...?)
} BtnStruct;

BtnStruct Btn0; // BtnStruct variable 
BtnStruct Btn1;

BtnStruct *BtnStructArray[2]; // array of pointers, pointed to BtnStruct type variables

BtnStructArray[0] = &Btn0; // fill the array with addresses of BtnStruct variables
BtnStructArray[1] = &Btn1;

int returnvalue; // just for test

int function0(int param) // say, there is a similar function1()
{
    int retval;

    // do something

    return(retval);
}

// In Run time:

BtnStructArray[0]->eventhandler = function0; // I try to give the address of the function, to the function pointer member
BtnStructArray[1]->eventhandler = function1;    


returnvalue = BtnStructArray[0]->eventhandler(10); // here I want to call the pointed function with parameter 
                                                   // But the function is not invoked
```

Solved! :)

I forgot the "&" before the "function0". This was the mistake.

So correctly:

```
BtnStructArray[0]->eventhandler = &function0;
```

To Barak:
Thanks for the tip, but because of some reasons, I have to use pointer array, instead of
simple structure array. But You helped me, because while I tested Your simplier version, I found the mistake. :)

To Askmish:
Maybe, my pasted code wasn't clear. Of course, I initialized the function pointers,
but as I have written above, I made a mistake.

To Babacar Diassé:
Yes,  the "In run time" mean, the next code are in the main() Thanks for all!

Comment: Well then step into that last last and tell us what happens. BTW, you might as well change `BtnStruct *BtnStructArray[2]` to `BtnStruct BtnStructArray[2]`. There doesn't seem to be any point in declaring an array of pointers and a pair of instances (`Btn0` and `Btn1`), and then set `BtnStructArray[0] = &Btn0` and `BtnStructArray[1] = &Btn1`.

Comment: Seems to be called properly to me http://ideone.com/jUQy5F

Comment: You should initialize `BtnStructArray[0]->eventhandler = function0; ` as such, the function pointers after the `main()`. You should not initialize them globally.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the array separately only inside your "runtime" (I suppose your run time is `main()` or a function called by main().) Alternatively, you can do this to initialize them at the declaration :

`BtnStruct *BtnStructArray[2] = {&Btn0, &Btn1}`